# Save div to MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I am working on a question portal for work. Now i have one problem after each question should be a button "Add to test". If you click on this button the content of the `content-div` will be saved to a MySQL table. I use the following code....

main code

```
<div id="content"> 
    This content shut be safe in the MySQL table.. 
</div> 
 <script> 
$(function(){ 
$('input.add').on('click',function(){ 
   var div_contents = $("#content").html(); 
            $.post('tomysql.php', { content: div_content }); 
}); 
}); 
</script>  
<input type="button" class="add" value="Add to Test" />
```

The tomysql.php

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root'); 

mysql_select_db($teste, $con); 

$div = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content']); 

$sql = "INSERT INTO teste (content) VALUES ('{$div}')"; 

$query = mysql_query($sql, $con); 
if($query) { 
     // Success! 
} else { 
     // Failure :( 
} 
?>
```

But it don´t work now. Where is the problem?

Comment: You need to explain better what you need to sort...

Comment: "content: div_content" is it correct? Because you defined "div_contents" in the previous line

Comment: This is highly unsafe. SQL injection here we go!

Comment: The server is only local reachable

Comment: Why are you inserting into testes? Isn't that painful? =D

Answer (score 2):

Putting your variable between single quotes treats it as text:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO teste (content) VALUES ('{$div}')";
```

try this instead:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO teste (content) VALUES ('". $div . "')";
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot password here

```
$con = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root','your_password');
```

Comment: I use no password at this time

Comment: @soqp92 so it should be blank `''`.

Answer (score 1):

ich have the answer of the problem

```
<div id="content"> 
<a href="google.de">google</a> 
Dieser inhalt soll in die MySQL Tabelle gespeichert werden..... 
</div> 
<script language="javascript"> 
    function test() 
    { 
        var div_content = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML; 
        location.href = "tomysql.php?c=" + div_content ,"tab";     
    } 
</script>
```

and the tomysql.php

```
<?php 

if (isset($_GET['c'])) 
{ 
    $con = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', ''); 


    mysql_select_db('teste', $con); 


    $sql = "INSERT INTO teste (content) VALUES ('". $_GET['c']. "')"; 

    $query = mysql_query($sql, $con); 
    if($query) { 
         echo("ok"); 
    } else { 
         echo("nicht ok"); 
    } 

    mysql_close($con); 
} 
?>
```

It works :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO teste (content) VALUES ('". addslashes($div) . "')";
```